# Нужны ли двоеточие и тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

Нужны ли двоеточие и тире?
*Стоимость на рынке (:) 15 000 рублей. Для вас (—) бесплатно.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше использовать тире, это соответствует интонации (паузам):

***Стоимость на рынке — 15 000 рублей. Для вас — бесплатно.***

> **2.** Тире ставится в неполных предложениях при параллелизме конструкций (предложений или частей предложения): *Тёркин — дальше. Автор — вслед* (Тв.); *Забора — нет. Ворот — нет. Границ — нет.*

[**Тире в неполном предложении**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=93) (справочник Розенталя)

Comment: Александр, а вы двоеточие в первом предложении никак не допускаете? Мне этот вариант больше нравится именно тем, что он разнообразен, нет параллельной конструкции. А подобрать объяснение можно всегда.

Comment: @Sharon  Почему не допускаю? Допускаю, поэтому и написал "лучше", а не "обязательно". Но двоеточие здесь, на мой взгляд, какое-то очень формальное, как будто на этикетке или в технических характеристиках. Можно и без всяких знаков. И симметрия знаков мне больше нравится.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.  Здесь интересна общая композиция, ведь предложения разноструктурные.  Сначала пусть будет "этикетка", а потом подчеркнутый переход к другому варианту. Но это мои фантазии)  Вы правы, кому что нравится.  Тем более  вы больше меня разбираетесь в художественных нюансах.  Голос от меня.

Comment: @Sharon Спасибо за комплимент!